# Show Sum of Columns in Pie Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In an SSRS 2008 report I've got 3 columns in a dataset with integer values. Now, I want to show sum of each column, in a pie chart. I tried putting Sum(field1), Sum(field2), ... in value fields, but it doesn't work correctly and creates several series.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you change your dataset? If yes, you could put the value you want to sum in only one column instead of 3.

Comment: No. The dataset is created with a very complex query and we have to use it as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:
I deleted all fields from "series" pane, and left Sum(field1), Sum(field2), ... in "data fields" pane. Then right clicked and on each name in "data fields" and in "series properties" entered my desired label for custom text on Legend tab. It seems all fine and working.
Thanks anyway.